# Is $V= V_1 + V_2$? horrible question but im confused

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage

[image]

So yeah , the answer seems true but i'm very skeptical about it since D3 is in the middle

Comment: Is there any way you could make the diagram clearer?

Comment: -1 for totally illegible diagram

Comment: Please edit your posts rather than re-posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm confused about voltages, I always remember how do you measure a voltage. You take two "needles", you stick them in any part of the circuit and you measure the potential difference. In this case $V_1$ gets measured by sticking the needles around $D_1$ and similarly with $V_2$ and $D_2$. $V$ is measured by sticking these needles in front of $D_1$ and behind $D_2$.

In circuits we pretend nothing happens in the wires, when we stick a needle $J$ in front of $D_1$,$K$ behind it, $L$ in front of $D_2$, and $M$ behind, there will be no potential difference between $K$ and $L$, because there is just a wire between them. So what is the potential difference $V$ between $J$ and $M$?

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram, the devices appear to be connected in parallel and $V$ appears to be voltage across the left-most wire which must be zero.

Since you've designated the devices with the letter $D$, I assume they are diodes but diodes aren't drawn as rectangles so I honestly can't write much more about this.

As I'm typing this, I see a comment to the effect that this is a duplicate so that's *all* I'm going to write about this.

Comment: its in french notation